# Timestamp offset from (day, hour, minute, etc.)

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Say I have a timestamp in Pandas:

```
Timestamp('2014-08-07 11:01:02')
```

I would like to get how many milliseconds is it **within the hour**. How can I do this in Pandas?

In the example above, I would be looking for the difference in milliseconds between:

- `Timestamp('2014-08-07 11:01:02')`
- `Timestamp('2014-08-07 11:00:00')`

If I have a series holding timestamps like the one below, how can I do that?

```
                 timestamp
1071   2014-08-07 11:01:02
3291   2014-08-07 11:01:00
3355   2014-08-07 05:01:00
3518   2014-08-07 05:01:03
4207   2014-08-07 13:01:03
5039   2014-08-07 18:01:04
5063   2014-08-07 23:01:03
6926   2014-08-07 06:01:02
6965   2014-08-07 06:01:02
7107   2014-08-07 05:01:01
Name: events_source_timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

### Update:

Trying @Jeff's answer. The following works:

```
In [210]: temp_df = m*(df.astype('i8')/m).astype('i8')
Out[210]: 
                         A_timestamp              B_timestamp
1                1407405600000000000      1407405600000000000
2                1407445200000000000      1407445200000000000
3                1407434400000000000      1407434400000000000
4                1407445200000000000      1407445200000000000
5                1407438000000000000      1407438000000000000
6                1407402000000000000      1407402000000000000
7                1407420000000000000      1407420000000000000
8                1407438000000000000      1407438000000000000
9                1407438000000000000      1407438000000000000
10               1407420000000000000      1407420000000000000
11               1407420000000000000      1407420000000000000
12               1407441600000000000      1407441600000000000
13               1407409200000000000      1407409200000000000
14               1407391200000000000      1407391200000000000
15               1407409200000000000      1407409200000000000
16               1407420000000000000      1407420000000000000
```

but then

`pd.DatetimeIndex(temp_df)`

fails with:

```
/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py in parse_time_string(arg, freq, dayfirst, yearfirst)
    472     except Exception as e:
    473         # TODO: allow raise of errors within instead
--> 474         raise DateParseError(e)
    475 
    476     if parsed is None:

DateParseError: unknown string format
```

Comment: Won't `(pd.Timestamp('2014-08-07 11:01:02')-pd.Timestamp('2014-08-07 11:00:00')).seconds * 1000` give you what you want? if you subtract a timestamp, this returns a timedelta. timedelta has a microseconds and seconds attribute but not milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks @EdChum. The problem I have is how to compute that timestamp that I substract from the original one (I have thousands of them in a timeseries and I can't type them manually).

Comment: I think you want something like `ts.minute * 60000 + ts.second * 1000` this would give you the number of milliseconds within the timestamps hour

Comment: @filmor the `microsecond` attribute returns `0` in this case, this is why I suggested using seconds and minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this, if `index` is a `DatetimeIndex`:

```
hour_as_integer = int(np.timedelta64(1, 'h') / np.timedelta64(1, 'ns'))
ms_as_integer = int(np.timedelta64(1, 'ms') / np.timedelta64(1, 'ns'))

ts.asi8 % hour_as_integer // ms_as_integer
```

The property `asi8` converts the index to its internal representation, i.e. 64 bit integers of the microsecond unix timestamp. Then the remainder of division by `10 ** 6 * 3600` (an hour in microseconds) is taken and the result is divided by `10 ** 3` to get milliseconds.

For a single `pd.Timestamp` object you can use

```
ts.asm8.astype("int64") % hour_as_integer // ms_as_integer
```

For a `Series` you can do

```
series.astype("int64") % hour_as_integer // ms_as_integer
```

With that last one I get

```
1071    62000
3291    60000
3355    60000
3518    63000
4207    63000
5039    64000
5063    63000
6926    62000
6965    62000
7107    61000
Name: events_source_timestamp, dtype: int64
```

for your data.

Note, though, that all of these will fail if you have a non-integer timezone offset.

Comment: Thanks but I get: `Timetamp object has no attribute 'asi8'`

Comment: Yes, as said, the first variant is for `pd.DatetimeIndex` objects, for single `pd.Timestamp`s you have to use `.asm8.astype("int64")`. I just wanted to prevent you from doing something like `index.map(lambda x: x.asm8.astype("int64") % (10 ** 9 * 3600) // 10 ** 6)` which is incredibly inefficient in comparison.

Comment: That is not true. You have everywhere an additional minute, aka 60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks @filmor. You are correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the canonical ways of doing this, see the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-deltas) for methods on Timedelta handling.

```
In [16]: s = Series([Timestamp('20140804 11:01:12'),Timestamp('20140804 11:00:00')])

In [17]: s
Out[17]: 
0   2014-08-04 11:01:12
1   2014-08-04 11:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [18]: (s-Timestamp('20140804 11:00:00')).astype('timedelta64[ms]')
Out[18]: 
0    72000
1        0
dtype: float64

In [19]: (s-Timestamp('20140804 11:00:00')) / np.timedelta64(1,'ms')
Out[19]: 
0    72000
1        0
dtype: float64
```

Here is a way to round the series to the nearest hour, though its a bit hacky atm,
and needs to be implemented as a proper DatetimeIndex method, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4314)

```
In [169]: m = int(1e9*60*60)

In [170]: rounded = Series(pd.DatetimeIndex(m*(s.astype('i8')/m).astype('i8')))

In [171]: rounded
Out[171]: 
0   2014-08-04 11:00:00
1   2014-08-04 11:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [172]: (s-rounded).astype('timedelta64[ms]')
Out[172]: 
0    72000
1        0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. The only problem left in the OP is getting the timestamp at the beginning of the hour (so that one can do this on many entries, not having to type the date manually). Any way to do that?

Comment: pls post an example, not sure what y r looking for

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff, I updated the OP with an example. I basically want to apply the solution that you described to **each item** in the series (i.e. get the offset with respect to **each timestamp**'s hour in `ms`)

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Not sure why it doesn't work here, if I do: `temp_df = m*(my_df.astype('i8')/m).astype('i8')` and then `pd.DateTimeIndex(temp_df)` I get `DateParseError: unknown string format`